# How to solve "Word too long" error in unix?

Tags: shell, unix, csh

I am writing a TC shell script called pl_dict in unix that accepts a list of English words in singular form as input, and prints out the plural form of each word in a separate line. It makes use of a file containing a list of words in the English language and another c program that accepts an English word in singular form as its argument, and prints the plural form of the word. 
Here is my code:

```
set dictionary = (/usr/share/dict/words)

set irregular = (/share/files/irregular.txt)

 #go over all the input words

foreach word ($argv[*])

    set irregularWord = `grep $word $irregular | cut -d" " -f1`

    #the word is found in irregular.txt file
    if ("$irregularWord" != "") then
       gcc -o pluralize pluralize.c
       ./pluralize -f irregular.txt $word

    else #the word is not found in the irregular file

       #search for it in the dictionary
       set realEnglishWord = `grep $word $dictionary`

       #the word is a real English word
       if ("$realEnglishWord" != "") then
          gcc -o pluralize pluralize.c
          ./pluralize $word
       else
          echo "$word":" word not found in dictionary."
       endif
    endif
end
```

It works just fine until I try to run this: pl_dict fish foot foox house mouse

Here the output I get is:

```
fish

feet

foox: word not found in dictionary.

Word too long.
```

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: Try some debugging echoes to see what $word is ... grep may be matching several lines from the dictionary ... If so, you can use awk and do an exact match of $1

Answer (score 4):

Try the following steps:

**Step 1:**

```
sudo apt-get install tcsh
```

**Step 2:**

```
sudo update-alternatives --config csh
```

Select **tcsh** from the list of choices available.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that that is a message of the program `pluralize`, and we need the text of the program to help you.

Also, you don't need to compile the program each time you run the script (`gcc` line). You can do it one time and then use the binary.

Answer (score 0):

Before tcsh 6.15, there is a limitation on the maximum length per line.
If I recall correctly, it is 4K characters.
The message is displayed if the limitation is violated.

This is often caused by the shell expanding a long variable.
I had run into this problem when I tried to expand a complex $PATH twice at the same line.

To solve it, find out the long variable first.
Use

```
env | grep VARIABLE_NAME
```

and/or

```
set | grep VARIABLE_NAME
```

before the variable expansion to inspect the suspected variable.

Also, because the result of `grep` might be thousands of lines (e.g. `is`),
if you want the exact result, you can use `<>` to specify boundary

```
grep "\<WORD\>" /usr/share/dict/words
```

or using awk, as commented by technosaurus.

Answer (score 0):

I just hit this same problem and it was the result of expanding a shell variable that was "too long".  I was also using grep like this:

set test_error = "`grep -P '^UVM_(ERROR|FATAL)\s+[^:]' $mylog`"

... which was matching multiple lines in $mylog and causing $test_error to become a huge multi-line string.  The fix was to use "-m 1" to cause grep to halt after the first match like this:

set test_error = "`grep -P -m 1 '^UVM_(ERROR|FATAL)\s+[^:]' $mylog`"

In my application, I only needed the first match.  Not sure if this will apply to your usage.